selinux mls mode took away all my root powers
SElinux mls mode took away all my root powers I do not have all root user privileges and I cannot disable SElinux. I cannot run SElinux commands.
[root@design var]# setenforce 0
setenforce: security_setenforce() failed: Permission denied

some files (shadow file ???)<br>
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Nov 14 12:00 sgml<br>
-?????????? ? ? ? ? ? shadow<br>
-?????????? ? ? ? ? ? shadow-<br>
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 44 Jun 23 2020 shells<br>
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Sep 23 12:59 skel<br>
-?????????? ? ? ? ? ? sudoers<br>
drwxr-x---. 2 root root 4096 Nov 10 21:05 sudoers.d


Boot with SELinux disabled, fix your rules and reboot.
